# how to read messages by packet with JmsTemplate of Sring

Tags: spring, spring-jms, jmstemplate

i have an outOfMemoryException while reading messages from a queue with 2 M of messages.
and i am trying to find a way to read messgages by 1000 for example .
here is my code

```
List<TextMessage> messages = jmsTemplate.browse(JndiQueues.BACKOUT, (session,browser) -> {
        Enumeration<?> browserEnumeration = browser.getEnumeration().;
        List<TextMessage> messageList = new ArrayList<TextMessage>();
        while (browserEnumeration.hasMoreElements()) {
            messageList.add((TextMessage) browserEnumeration.nextElement());
        }
        return messageList;
    });
```

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Perform the browse on a different thread and pass the results subset to the main thread via a `BlockingQueue<List<TextMessage>>`. e.g. a `LinkedBlockingQueue` with a small capacity.

The browsing thread will block when the queue is full. When the main thread removes an entry from the queue, the browser can add a new one.

Probably makes sense to have a capacity at least 2 so that the next list is available immediately.

Comment: Hello Gary ,my question was ,if there is in JmsTemplate a method to get Messages by a certain number (1000 ) for example .  because i dont know if browse method loads the messages on memory that causes a memory leak . or is it because of adding messages to the list that loads two millions of messages and causes the outofMemory exception

Comment: It has nothing to do with the template; the template simply provides you with a browser to use, it doesn't do the browsing; it's because YOUR code is reading all the messages into memory; use the technique I described to avoid this.